# NFC Service Dead on clover device

Tags: android, nfc

working on NFC tag android app using clover device and most of the time NFC service is not working ,code attached on below link :
https://github.com/shaelhaldkar/BpNFCDemo

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reason why that code is probably not working.

1. Don't try and run `enableForegroundDispatch` and `enableReaderMode` at the same time as these are 2 API's to do the same thing.

You have some `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {` lines but don't  use the else cause.

So the code should look like:-

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   // Use enableReaderMode
} else {
   // Use enableForegroundDispatch
}
```

2. Both `enableForegroundDispatch` and `enableReaderMode` need to be only enabled when the app is in the foreground and disabled when not in the foreground

Thus you should only enable the NFC Api's in `onResume` and disable them in `onPause`